# Search in Visual Studio cannot find word that has tens of instances in text

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Search cannot find clearly visible word "sound". After manually marking words "sound" and finding all instances, search started to run and found all instances. I am hobby coder so I apologize if asking anything obvious.

[image]

Comment: I suggest that you could use 'ctrl shirt +F' to use whole find in the whole solution。

Answer (score 4):

You have "Selection" in the scope box meaning it will only search within the text you have currently selected with your cursor, which in your case appears to be none.  Broaden the search scope to Current Block, Document, Project, Solution, etc.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so problem was in too wide scope? Current code is not so big, what Visual Studio was searching is beyond my mind. Comparing to VS 2015 everything lasts three times more. Or fifty times sometime. Also I am not sure if it is OK to show "not found" message.

Comment: No the problem was too narrow of a scope.

Comment: Ah thanks again. Still what happened "intuitive" attribute of Visual Studio. I've certainly didn't choose 'Selection'.

Comment: In my experience VS has a minor flaw where it randomly sets that to "selection".  You just need to be mindful of the scope whenever you're searching.